# Accessing props in child vue component data function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the below child component. The props are updated from an input selector in the parent. Why does `level: this.globalForm.level` not update the child's `level`

Parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="form-container">
      <select class="form-control" v-model="level">
        <option v-for="level in options" v-bind:key="level">{{ level }}</option>
      </select>
      <button @click="submit()">Create</button>
    </div>
    <child v-bind:globalForm="globalForm"/>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
inputFiled;
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      level: "",
      globalForm: {
        level: ""
      },
      options: ["level1", "level2", "level3"]
    };
  },
  components: {
    child
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.globalForm.level = this.level;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    level() {
      this.globalForm.level = this.level;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-container">
      <option v-for="level in options" v-bind:key="level">{{ level }}</option>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: { globalForm: Object },
  data() {
    return {
      options: ["level1","level2","level3",],
      level: this.globalForm.level //this does not update the child's level component
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the child component rendered in the parent one?

i cant see something like `<child :globalForm='globalForm'> </child>` in the parent

Comment: sorry about that. I updated it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

`level` should be a computed property on the child so that you can detect changes in the prop. You are setting `level` in the `data` function, so updates to the prop never make it to `level`.

Below you'll find a minimal example on what I think you want to achieve.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.component('parent', {
  template: `
  <div class="parent">
    <b>PARENT</b>
    <div class="form-container">
      <select class="form-control" v-model="level">
        <option v-for="level in options" v-bind:key="level">{{ level }}</option>
      </select>
      <button @click="submit()">Create</button>
    </div>
    <child v-bind:globalForm="globalForm"/>
  </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    level: "",
    globalForm: {
      level: ""
    },
    options: ["level1", "level2", "level3"]
  }),
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.globalForm.level = this.level;
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div class="form-container child">
      <p><b>Child</b></p>
      Level: {{ level }}
  </div>
  `,
  props: {
    globalForm: Object
  },
  computed: {
    level() {
      return  this.globalForm.level;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: darkgray;
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.child {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent></parent>
</div>
```

**More Detailed explanation**

There are couple of errors on your code that I'll go through.

**In your child component**

When initializing your component, `this` is not available inside the `data` function, so `this.globalForm` will be undefined. An error is thrown in the console when reproducing it.

```
data() {
    return {
      options: ["level1","level2","level3",], // this looks like duplicated code from the parent
      level: this.globalForm.level // throws error
    };
 }
```

To fix that error, you can get the `vm` context from the parameters of `data` **But this is not the solution for your question**.

```
data(vm) { // note vm
    return {
      level: vm.globalForm.level // note vm
    };
 }
```

The real problem is that `level: this.globalForm.level` **runs only once**, in your component initialization, so level is `undefined`. When the `globalForm` prop changes, `level` has already been initialized and it will not change (data returns a new object so the reference to the prop is lost).

You want convert `level` to be a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) so that changes to the prop can be detected and the inner value returned. See code snippet above.